# How to filter collection by a tuple Enum

Tags: rust, enums

I have a part of a program that functions like this, and I need a way to filter a collection using an enum, but I'm not sure of the best way to allow all possibilities of the 'sub-enum'.

In the example, I would like to print all weapons, regardless of what type it is.

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Item {
    Armor,
    Consumable,
    Weapons(WeaponTypes),
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
enum WeaponTypes {
    Axe,
    Bow,
    Sword,
}

fn main() {
    let mut stuff = BTreeMap::<&str, Item>::new();
    
    stuff.insert("helmet of awesomeness", Item::Armor);
    stuff.insert("boots of the belligerent", Item::Armor);
    stuff.insert("potion of eternal life", Item::Consumable);
    stuff.insert("axe of the almighty", Item::Weapons(WeaponTypes::Axe));
    stuff.insert("shortbow", Item::Weapons(WeaponTypes::Bow));
    stuff.insert("sword of storm giants", Item::Weapons(WeaponTypes::Sword));
    
    stuff
        .iter()
        // this filter works exactly as intended
        .filter(|e| *e.1 == Item::Armor)
        // using this filter instead doesn't work because it expects a WeaponType inside
        //.filter(|e| e.1 == Item::Weapons)
        .map(|e| e.0.to_string())
        .for_each(|e| println!("'{}'", e));
}
```

I tried using `Item::WeaponType(_)` because that kinda looks like the `_` match case, but that wouldn't work either.

I could chain together the equality expressions as a last resort (`e.1 == Item::Weapons(WeaponType::Axe) || e.1 == Item::Weapons(WeaponType::Sword) ...`), but that would require like 8 different comparisons, and I feel like there should be a better way that I haven't found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe, you are looking for a [matches!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html) macro:

```
.filter(|e| matches!(e.1, Item::Weapons(_))
```

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=efe0c91651ffbf952d07d49f1d6b19ce

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The following is necessary to make this work:

```rust
.filter(|e| match *e.1 { Item::Weapons(_) => true, _ => false })
// or .filter(|e| if let Item::Weapons(_) = *e.1 { true } else { false })
```

You can't create an enum variant which has associated data without its associated data, which is what you tried to do. You have to pattern match the value in `*e.1` against some kind of pattern, in this case, `Item::Weapons(_)` with the `_` placeholder as payload value in the enum, since you don't care what exactly is inside the enum.

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=42d462c4c83900202b0c00c7ba612f77